# Jquery makes changes only on screen

Tags: jquery, html, width

My html:

```
<div class="fi-container">
   <div class="fi-row"> 

      <div class="fi-cell"> <!-- content --> </div>
      <div class="fi-cell"> <!-- content --> </div>
      <div class="fi-cell"> <!-- content --> </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$('.fi-cell').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).parent().closest('div').css("background-color", 'yellow');
    });
$('.fi-cell').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).parent().closest('div').css("background-color", 'inherit');
    });
});
```

I have a page which is much wider than screen. And my script is onlye working with elements which can be seen on the page before scrolling to the right (when I scroll to the right, the script is not working, and the background-color doesn't change.) DIVs creating table with data.

I would like `background-color` to change on whole `<div class='fi-row'>` width, not only the first width of the page load.

https://jsfiddle.net/7npL68jj/

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: ok. give me a sec.

Comment: i've edited question. please, scroll on right and u will see :)

Comment: Your `fi-row` is 100% wide.  Add this `.fi-row { border:5px solid red;}`

Comment: ok. i see what do you want to say... but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Kafus no, I also couldn't see how to fix it, hence a comment to confirm what you already guessed.

Comment: i changed css: `fi-row { table-layout:fixed; display:table; }` and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.fi-row {
   table-layout: fixed;
   display: table;
};

.fi-cell {
   display: table-cell;
};
```

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7npL68jj/4/

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. It's working but only without adding additional code for `fi-cell`. Thank you.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code a bit, removed unnecessary margins and added a `box-sizing: border-box` for better practice. You can check the updated fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.